# count number of times prime factor repeat in final multilply

Tags: number-theory

We have a number $n$ represented as its prime factorization pi of
size $m$, i.e $n = p_1p_2p_3p_4\cdot p_m$.
we Know that product of all divisors of $n$ taken modulo $10^9+7$
is the password. Now we want to calculate this value.
I want to know how many times a prime factor is going to repeat in final answer 
so that I can apply for each prime factor.

suppose if the number are 2  ,2, 3  then $n = 12$ and then 12 will have factors 
as 1,2,3,4,6,12 and 2^6 will contribute in final answer.

Comment: First-> https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22658?#comment-271626

Second->https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22658?#comment-271616 I found two  comments  I am not getting

Comment: You should show what comments you are not understanding so we can answer your real question.

Comment: why we need two prefix and suffix arrays

Comment: Please help me I am trying to under to understand from 2 days this problem ,
after here no place left

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the product of all the divisors of $n$, given the prime factorization?  When $n=12$, is the answer you are looking for equal to $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot6\cdot12$?

Comment: Let the number be $p1^α1·p2^α2...·pk^αk$. Now, consider an individual prime pi. What is it's power in the final answer? It's$ pi^(1 + 2 + ... + αi)(α1 + 1)(α2 + 1)...(αi - 1 + 1)(αi + 1 + 1)...(αk + 1)$. We need to find this value for every prime divisor of the number and multiply them together.

Comment: I want to understand the above statement @saulspatz

Comment: In the final answer means here product of all divisors

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Let the number be $p1^α1·p2^α2...·pk^αk$. Now, consider an individual prime pi. What is it's power in the final answer? It's $ pi^(1 + 2 + ... + αi)(α1 + 1)(α2 + 1)...(αi - 1 + 1)(αi + 1 + 1)...(αk + 1)$. We need to find this value for every prime divisor of the number and multiply them together.

Comment: Please help please

Comment: You have still not asked a clear question, simply referring to two links that you don't understand.  I can't see what you are asking about.  Voting to close

Answer (score 1):

Let the prime factorization of $n$ be $$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}.$$  We wish to compute the product of the divisors of $n$.

To begin with, I claim the number of divisors of $n$ is $$\tau(n)=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_k)\tag{1}$$  To see this, note that the divisors are precisely the numbers of the form $$p_1^{j_1}p_2^{j_2}\cdots p_k^{j_k},\ 0\leq j_i\leq a_i,\ 1\leq i\leq k$$ so that there are $1+a_i$ choices for each exponent $j_i$.

Now to return to the original question, how many factors of $p_i$ are there is the product of all the divisors of $n$?  First of all, there are $$\rho_i := (1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_{i-1})(1+a_{i+1})\cdots(1+a_k)\tag{2}$$ divisors of $n/{p_i}^{k_i}$. Each of these $\rho_i$ divisors may be multiplied by $p_i$ or ${p_i}^2$ or ${p_i}^3$, ..., or by ${p_i}^{a_i}$ so it will contribute $$1+2+3+\cdots+k_i={a_i(a_i+1)\over2}$$ factors of $p_i$.  Therefore, the exponent of $p_i$ in the product of all the divisors of $n$ will be $${\rho_ia_i(1+a_i)\over2}$$ and the product of all the divisors of $n$ is $$\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\rho_i a_i (1+a_i)/2}\tag{3}=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i\tau(n)/2}$$ since $\tau(n)=(1+a_i)\rho_i$.  Of course, this can be further reduced to $n^{\tau(n)/2}$ but this wouldn't be as convenient for computation.  You need to compute $p_i^{a_i\tau(n)/2}$ for each prime, reducing modulo $10^9+7$ as you go along, and multiply all the results.

**EDIT**

Every divisor of $n$ may be written in the form $p_i^{k_i}d$ where $d$ is not divisible by $p_i$.  If we are trying to determine the exponent of $p_i$, we only care about the cases where $k_i\geq1,$ and of course, we must have $k_i\leq a_i.$  That gives a total of $a_i(1+a_i)/2$ factors of $p_i$, and we may repeat this calculation for every divisor $d$ of $n/p_i^{a_i}$.

Comment: $ divisors of $n/{p_i}^{k_i}$. Each of these $\rho_i$ divisors may be multiplied by $p_i$ or ${p_i}^2$ or ${p_i}^3$, ..., or by ${p_i}^{a_i}$ so it will contribute $$1+2+3+\cdots+k_i={a_i(a_i+1)\over2}$$ factors of $p_i$

Comment: Please explain above line I don't know how to use mathjax

Comment: Look at the MathJax tutorial I linked.  I'll try to add some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much sir I was searching for it from two days may god bless you